# Handling Orphaned Data In A Restful Service

Tags: rest

Lets suppose I have a RESTful service which has a list of tasks.

```
GET mycorp/api/v1/tasks
```

Each of these tasks can have one or more contexts.

```
GET mycorp/api/v1/tasks?context=somecontext
```

Over the course of usage, a user deletes a batch of tasks.

```
DELETE mycorp/api/v1/tasks?context=somecontext
```

Lets assume once this action is performed that we have a few contexts that are now orphaned in the system because of the DELETE action above. Lets also assume that it is ok to have orphaned context's to save the user having to enter the same context's over and over.

If the user DID want to remove these contexts explicitly, what would the correct way to do this be in the context of REST? I am naturally gravitating towards two options.

```
DELETE mycorp/api/v1/tasks?context=somecontext&&deleteorphancontexts=true
```

And also

```
DELETE mycorp/api/v1/contexts?isorphaned=true
```

I am still new to REST and what to make sure the api I build is rigid an sensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, REST is not a strict set of guidelines, so there is no definite answer for this, but I think it would help you to view the different URLs as resources (which is after all what REST is all about).

When you send a DELETE request to the server, you are instructing it to delete the resource at that location. In your example you are presuming that you are deleting the contents of a collection, but you are actually instructing the server to delete the collection itself. So if you issued a GET request immediately after, you should expect to get a 204 (No Content) response, instead of a 200 response with an empty collection. If that is suitable, then your problem is solved.

In my opinion it would be better to use the DELETE request for individual contexts/tasks, as the opposite of a PUT request. It is more correct to modify a collection by issuing a POST request containing a command to delete the specified contents.

In this way you can POST to

mycorp/api/v1/contexts

and send a command that instructs the server to delete all orphans.

The reason I prefer this, is that you are treating the context path as a collection in its own right where some items may be orphaned.

Normally when you are in doubt POST is your friend because it is the joker of HTTP.

Comment: Makes sense, I didn't think about the fact that delete should mean the whole resource as opposed to entities in the resource where x = y.